# Fetch notifications by using spring-social

Tags: spring-social

I am developing an application to fetch comments,notifications,updates etc of a user from Facebook by using spring-social.But I am not getting any api to fetch notifications of the user.

Comment: Anyone will please reply if it is not there then why?Suggest some alternative way.Waiting for for the reply.